# USB Inspection camera

Tags: camera, webcam

I have a USB Inspection camera, identified as 
"Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 300k Pixel Camera"

This is mounted at `/dev/video0` and I can capture stills using `fswebcam`

I would like to use this as an Inspection camera i.e. display live images - either on the Pi (or preferably on another Pi on the same local network).

The last time I used it (on a laptop, years ago) it "just worked".

I have searched this site for webcam, but not found anything relevant.

The camera has an in-built LED light, with an switch, which presumably needs software to control.